# Top elements are hidden in ScrollView with white space at bottom. How to fix the issue

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

I am adding text views to a linearLayout which is in a scrollView. 
in 80 tags around 30 are lost on top. And there is some white space at the bottom of the scrollView. As you can see in the picture, top tag is cut(top of scrollView).

[image]

ScrollView Xml:

```
   <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/backLayout"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonSeparator"
    android:background="@color/white">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/tagsLayout"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

text item xml:

```
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/tag_background"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tag"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:alpha="0.70"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding text views to linear layout:

```
    for(String tag: tagList){
        View tagHeader = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.tag_item, null);
        TextView tagText = (TextView) tagHeader.findViewById(R.id.tag);
        tagText.setText(tag);
        tagsLayout.addView(tagHeader);
    }
```

I found few solutions that said to remove gravity from the layout. still same after  removed the gravity parameter. fillViewport set to true did not work either

Comment: What is the parent of ScrollView? If its a RelativeView with a toolbar view as first element, it could be overlapping your ScrollView. Please paste the entire layout file.

Comment: I tried with just the scrollView. problem is not just the one tag that's getting cut in t he top. over 30 tags are getting hidden. as you can see, its  top of the scrollView. there is no layout overlapping on it

Comment: OK. I'm not sure why that's happening, but can you try using a RecyclerView here? The way you are doing it now, even the elements that are not being currently displayed are taking up memory. Using a recyclerview, it can be handled more efficiently. I'm not sure if this would solve your problem.

Comment: @notsopopularguy will try. thanks